# Script to browser problem PHP

Tags: php, plugin-development

this is what I want to do

Output here (A - FB and None FB):

```
John    facebook
Mary    facebook
Peter   ?
Nicolas facebook
Camilla ?
Peter   ?
Sam ?
Jacko   ?
Ola facebook
Erick   facebook
```

And here (B - None FB):

```
Peter   ?
Camilla ?
Peter   ?
Sam ?
Jacko   ?
```

And here (C - FB):

```
John    facebook
Mary    facebook
Nicolas facebook
Ola facebook
Erick   facebook
```

Some of them, choose by A
and another, choose by B.
and another, choose by C.
But how, A, B or C?

I have used this script:

```
$args = array (
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page'=>'-1',
'orderby' => 'post_title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'value' => get_the_ID(),
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'land',
        'value' => get_query_var('land'),
    ),
)
$query = new WP_Query($arg);
while($query->have_posts()) :
$query->the_post();
echo get_the_title();

//This is correct in programming, but error is webbrowser, that is &facebook=
if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "facebook", true))
    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "facebook", true)";
else
    echo "?";
endwhile;


//if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "facebook", false)) {  //FB
//if(!get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "facebook", false)) { //none
//if(!get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "facebook", true)) {  //None FB
//if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "facebook", true)) {   //both
//No

 //http://www.dot.com/post/?facebook=?
//get_query_var('facebook');
//No
```